# mosquitto broker shuts down when terminal is closed

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I have a problem with mosquitto running on my pi 3. I use it to transmit temperature and humidity from several sensors in my appartement (433 mhz) to my node red which is also running on my pi.
When I start the broker I can see the messages coming in to my node red but as soon as I close the putty terminal somehow the broker seems to stop transmitting.

My command is this:

```
rtl_433 -F json -M utc | mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.178.37 -t home/rtl_433 -l
```

When I start putty again and want to start the broker again i get the error that the address is already in use.

How can I change this that mosquitto won't stop? In Node red I see that the mosquitto is still running but somehow it is not transmitting the data.

Comment: Either run it as a *service* like this... https://www.thedigitalpictureframe.com/ultimate-guide-systemd-autostart-scripts-raspberry-pi/ or run it under `nohup` like this... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47231/400632

Comment: This is not the broker stopping, but your publishing command. You need to either run it under `screen` or write a service wrapper. But as it is this question is Off Topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on SuperUser or Unix & Linux.

Comment: thanks for the tipp. I will keep that in mind.